# Pointwise convergence of a function where convergence to multiple values occur at a single point

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Consider,

$$
f_n(x)=\frac{1-nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2}
$$

where, $$x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

It is clear to me that not including $x = 0$, each function point converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The confusion is the convergence at $x = 0$.
It seems to converge to both $f = 1$ and $f = \frac{-1}{8}$.
On differentiating and setting equal to zero, the stationary points occur at  $$x = 0, f_n(x) = 1$$  $$x_n = \pm{\sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}}, f_n(x) = \frac{-1}{8}$$
Both function values don't depend on $n$, however as $n \to \infty$,

$$x_n = \pm{\sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}} \to 0$$

Which would suggest that as $x \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$,
$$f_n(x) \to \frac{-1}{8}$$ and $$f_n(x) \to 1$$

Could someone explain to me what is going on, I suspect it has something to do with converging to disjoint functions?

Does this mean the sequence of functions does not converge pointwise (and thus not uniformly)? How would I go about formally proving this with $\epsilon$ quantifers.

Comment: Note that it's $f_n(x_n) = -\frac{1}{8}$, so the function and the point itself depends on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an entirely complete answer (i.e. there's no $\epsilon,\delta$ ) but this is too long to fit in a comment. We say $f_n\to f$ pointwise if $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$. From this definition, it's clear that $f(0)=1$ but is zero otherwise. This is enough to prove that the convergence is not uniform, because uniform convergence would imply that $f$ is continuous.

What you have found is that there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_n)\neq f(0)$. This has no bearing on the pointwise limit because of the pointwise limit's definition. I believe that this is another proof that convergence isn't uniform, because uniform convergence should imply that those two limits are equal.

Comment: I believe I may have mistaken pointwise convergence previously then. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the intuition is that the reason this is point-wise convergent is because "If I choose any point, as I take $n \to \infty$, I know what that point becomes", and so if the function converges to $0$ for any $x \neq 0$ and is $1$ exactly at $x = 0$ then we have pointwise convergence. Would this be the right interpretation?

Comment: Yep, basically. Pointwise convergence is looking at the values of $f_n$ for a constant $x$. If those function values converge to an number for each $x$ individually, you have pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense, the epsilon-delta proof won't be hard in that case. Cheers.